# Maintaining different requirements files for virtualenv and pip

Tags: python, bash, pip, virtualenv

I know that I can use `pip freeze` to assist in creating a list of my requirements for my virtual environment, but I'm having a bit of difficulty managing all of my different packages.

I want to keep some packages separate for development and production, and it is unwieldy to have production and development requirement files since I am using so many packages (many of which are common to each other.) How can I more efficiently keep my production and development packages separate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not difficult at all.

Let's say you have one requirements file for production: `production.txt` and one for development: `development.txt`. Create a third file, `shared.txt`, that has all of the dependencies in common. Then, in each respective requirements file, list the dependencies exclusive to your desired environment. At the head of `development.txt` and `production.txt`, link to your `shared.txt` using `-r shared.txt`. Each file will now load the common dependencies before loading exclusive dependencies.

Example:

**shared.txt**

```
SharedExamplePackage1
SharedExamplePackage2
SharedExamplePackage3
SharedExamplePackage4
SharedExamplePackage5
```

**development.txt**

```
-r shared.txt
DevExamplePackage1
DevExamplePackage2
```

**production.txt**

```
-r shared.txt
ProductionExamplePackage1
ProductionExamplePackage2
ProductionExamplePackage3
```

Answer (score 5):

You can include one requirements file into another by using:

```
-r more_requirements.txt
```

For example, the `dev-requirements.txt` file can contain the production requirements plus the additional development packages:

```
-r requirements.txt
mock
tox
```

(and so on)

Comment: can I put it in condition? I don't want to install some apps on heroku (production) but seems first solution does't work for heroku - cannot detect the buildpack